# Tree menu correct divs style

Tags: html, css, menu

Im trying to create an treemenu for categories,im creating it with a plugin jquery.treemenu and some css so my first tree menu looks like that:
[image]

After that i decided to add properties on it just below the category name so i filled it in div and thats how it looks like now:
[image]

Thats how im building my html for treemenu:

```
    @model  List<Model.DTO.CategoryDTO>

@{
    TagBuilder ol = new TagBuilder("ddd");

    ol.InnerHtml = "";

    <style>
.properties_list .property_item
{
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:15px;
}
.properties_list
{
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: left;
}
.property_item
{
    margin-right: 3px;
}
    </style>
    foreach (var category in Model)
    {

        var propertiesList = new TagBuilder("ul");
        propertiesList.AddCssClass("list-group properties_list");
        if (category.PropertyList != null && category.PropertyList.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var prop in category.PropertyList)
            {
                var propertyItem = new TagBuilder("li");
                propertyItem.AddCssClass("btn btn-active property_item list-group-item");
                propertyItem.SetInnerText(prop.Name);
                propertiesList.InnerHtml += propertyItem;
            }
        }

        TagBuilder li = new TagBuilder("li");
        li.Attributes.Add("data-id", category.Id.ToString());
        li.Attributes.Add("data-name", category.Name);
        li.InnerHtml = "<b class=\"namecategory\">" + category.Name + "</b>"
            + propertiesList
            + "<small class=\"handler transperent btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-move text-muted\"></small>"
            + "<button class=\"btn transperent hidden btn-config \"   data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#ModalUpdate\" ><small class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-cog\"></small></button>"
            + "<button class=\"btn transperent hidden btn-add \"      data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#ModalAdd\"    ><small class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-plus\"></small></button>"
            + "<button class=\"btn transperent hidden btn-remove \" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#ModalDelete\" ><small class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-minus\" ></small></button>";
        TagBuilder ul = new TagBuilder("ul");
        if (category.ChildrenCategory != null)
        {
            ul.InnerHtml = Html.Partial("FlexibleListCategories", category.ChildrenCategory).ToString();
        }


        li.InnerHtml += ul;
        //li.InnerHtml += propertiesList;
        ol.InnerHtml += li;

    }
    MvcHtmlString ms = new MvcHtmlString(ol.InnerHtml);


    @ms
}
```

So question is how to style my new div with name and properties,it should looks like first one tree but just with properties below.

Outer html of tree menu for one category:

```
          <ul class="tree serialization">
                    <style>
.properties_list .property_item
{
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:15px;
}
.properties_list
{
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: left;
}
.property_item
{
    margin-right: 3px;
}
    </style>
<li data-id="5" data-name="Mobile phones"><b class="namecategory">Mobile phones</b><ul class="list-group properties_list"><li class="btn btn-active property_item list-group-item">wqe</li><li class="btn btn-active property_item list-group-item">prop</li></ul><small class="handler transperent btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-move text-muted"></small><button class="btn transperent hidden btn-config "   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalUpdate" ><small class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></small></button><button class="btn transperent hidden btn-add "      data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalAdd"    ><small class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></small></button><button class="btn transperent hidden btn-remove " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalDelete" ><small class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" ></small></button><ul>    <style>
.properties_list .property_item
{
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:15px;
}
.properties_list
{
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: left;
}
.property_item
{
    margin-right: 3px;
}
    </style>
```

Comment: Please convert your MVC code to the output html. The server code doesn't relevant.

Comment: Okay,give me a second.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't be more clear. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your question will include working example it will easier for us to help you.